# using HTMLparser on multiple calls

Tags: python, url, html-parsing

I am bulding my own parser which was not using the search engine API and only returning the URL's with the search results in the bing environment, using python.

I created the usual `HTMLParser` class and in the `main` i created the class instance

```
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(content)
```

This works for single calls but if I change the content and put this in a loop the feed does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on "the feed does not work"? Is there an error/traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you feed the parser instance a new document you should reset it.

E.g. `parser.reset()`

See: http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: even the reset doesnt work. Can you please checkout the code i editing along with my question and help

Comment: The global variable count was not being set to 0 again when i called the instance probably it was locally setting it. in the main i tried resetting it to 0 after every reset call and it works.

Thanks for the reset() function though !! :)